# Asyncpraw unclosed client session withing giving an client session object in logs

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp, reddit, praw, asyncpraw

I was able to implement asyncpraw and it works pretty well and faster but the issue I am facing right now is that I get en error in the logs. The error I get is

I was able to implement asyncpraw and it works pretty well and faster but the issue I am facing right now is that I get en error in the logs. The error I get is

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x15394a310>
```

​

I am getting all the text for all the hot comments and here is my code

```
class SubredditF:  
 def __init__(self, token) -> None:  
 self.reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(  
 client_id=environ.get("CLIENT_ID"),  
 client_secret=environ.get("SECRET_ID"),  
 user_agent="Trenddit/0.0.2",  
 refresh_token=token,  
 username=environ.get("USER_ID"),  
 password=environ.get("PASSWORD"),  
)  
 self.token = token  
 self.reddit.read_only = True
```

My code for getting detail of getting hot posts is

```
async def get_hot_posts(self, subredditName, num):
        res = []
        subreddit = await self.reddit.subreddit(subredditName)
        async for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=num):
            res.append({
                "title": submission.title,
                "author": str(submission.author),
                "nsfw": submission.over_18,
                "upvote_ratio": submission.upvote_ratio
            })
         
       return res
```

The code in which I call it for API endpoint is

```
@subreddit_routes.route("/subreddit_posts", methods=["GET"])
async def subreddit_get_posts():
    token = FirebaseC().get_token()
    sub = SubredditF(token)
    res = await (sub.get_hot_posts("Canada", 100))
    response = jsonify(authError=True, data={"data": res})
    return response
```